# SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54, address = 192.168.178.117, port = 52699

Tags: flutter

In flutter when i try to upload mp4 video to my local server return me this

```
SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54, address = 192.168.178.117, port = 52699
```

i used

```
    AssetEntity asset = toUpload[i];
    final byteData = await asset.originBytes;
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
      ..fields['fileName'] = _imageNames[i]
      ..files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('image', byteData));
```

Is this a client problem or a server problem ?
I use this version of http

```
 http: ^0.12.2
```

Comment: Have you give the internet permissions in the manifest for android.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in my backend.
Using quarkus in application.properties i add

```
 quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size = 200M
```

Comment: something like ddos mitigation? seems interesting to me, a beginner